# Procedure to add colums to all tables starting with prefix

Tags: mysql

I need to add a certain amount of colums to all tables starting with the prefix "art_".
If i do this manually it will take a long time as they are over 100 tables with this prefix.

Can i use a procedure to modify all these tables ? And if so, What would the procedure look like ?

Thanks in advance for any assistance

Comment: want you to do it with SQL only or a shell script ?

Comment: @BerndBuffen SQL only

Comment: could you an example of what would be the final output? like do you want to loop through each table and add same exact number of columns for each table? how is it going to be like. if you can explain I could write an algorithm

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia Yes, i would like it to loop through each table and add 3 colums ( same 3 colums for each table). The output would be that all the tables with prefix "art_" have now 3 nwe colums .

Comment: ok i will update the solution. You want to achieve this in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create cursor in the stored procedure for your requirement.

```
select * 
from information_schema.tables
```

Above query will return you all tables from your databases.

```
    DELIMITER $$

    CREATE PROCEDURE `addprefix`()
    BEGIN
    DECLARE r_table_name VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE loop_end INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = "db_name";
         DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET loop_end = 1;
         OPEN cur1;
         rootLoop : LOOP
              FETCH cur1 INTO r_table_name;
              IF loop_end THEN
                   LEAVE rootLoop;
              END IF;
              IF SUBSTR(r_table_name,0,4) = "art_" THEN 
                  your COLUMN ADD CODE;
              END IF;
    END LOOP rootLoop;
    CLOSE cur1;
    END$$

    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I really do not know my way around Procedures ... 
I got error :
#1193 - Unknown system variable 'loop_end'

Comment: updated my code with one declare statement..

DECLARE loop_end INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

Answer (score 1):

So you will need list of tables in an array.

Lets say : `$table_names` is an array with list of tables. If you have 100s of table. you can use a query to get list of table names too `select * from information_schema.tables`

```
foreach($table_names as $table_name)
{
    ALTER TABLE '$table_name'
    ADD COLUMN `art_col1` VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL AFTER `last_col`,
    ADD COLUMN `art_col2` VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL AFTER `col1`,
    ADD COLUMN `art_col3` VARCHAR(12) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AFTER `col2`;
}
```

Comment: ofcourse you need to do $sql = the query i wrote at the top and execute query etc. normal process